# It is possible to fetch gmail all attachment list and download it?

Tags: android, download, gmail, attachment

I want to fetch all attachments from gmail account and display it in list view and when user can select one or multiple attachment and download it in sd card.

Is it possible to fetch all attachment and download it?

Please help if anyone has ever done this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible directly

we have to use external api like gmail api in java and integrate that gmail api to our android application

here is the link for gmail api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: Its possible directly i have found one solution

Comment: What is the solution you found? If you post it here that would be useful for others.